# DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique in hardhat test

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I've got a problem with hardhat test.

I copied a library to my project/contracts dirctory and imported it in another contracts.

```
import "./IterableMapping.sol";

contract NewContract {
    ...
}
```

I wrote a test in which NewContract is deployed.

```
const IterableMapping = await ethers.getContractFactory("IterableMapping");
const iterableMapping = await IterableMapping.deploy();

const NewContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("NewContract", {
  libraries: {
    IterableMapping: iterableMapping.address,
  },
});
```

But the test failed with the belowing error.

```
 HardhatError: HH701: There are multiple artifacts for contract "IterableMapping", please use a fully qualified name.

Please replace IterableMapping for one of these options wherever you are trying to read its artifact:

contracts/IterableMapping.sol:IterableMapping
contracts/Lib.sol:IterableMapping
```

Anyone can help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As the error says you seem to define a contract called `IterableMapping` in multiple files. The files are listed in the error message. Could you share the content of the files?

Comment: Yes, there were two declarations on the two files. But I didn't reference one file at all. Anyway, I removed that file, and the error vanished. Thanks.

Comment: Most Solidity frameworks are configured to automatically compile all files in your contracts folder.

Answer (score 4):

The error message means that instead of

```
const IterableMapping = await ethers.getContractFactory("IterableMapping");
```

You Should Use

```
const IterableMapping = await ethers.getContractFactory("contracts/IterableMapping.sol:IterableMapping");
```

OR

```
const IterableMapping = await ethers.getContractFactory("contracts/Lib.sol:IterableMapping");
```

Depending on which of these contracts you meant to use